# CEFSharp Winforms calling controls on forms from Handlers

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Not sure if what i'm trying to achieve is possible but i have am trying to create a custom downloaded bar in CefSharp winforms.

I have created a control on my main form that i want to make visible after a files has been downloaded, the problem i have is that i can't reference the form from the DownloadHandler.

If i create a new instance of the form it open a new blank form which i don't want.

here is my code.

```
class DownloadHandler: IDownloadHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

    public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
    {
        var handler = OnBeforeDownloadFired;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, downloadItem);
        }

        if (!callback.IsDisposed)
        {
            using (callback)
            {
                callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
    {
        var handler = OnDownloadUpdatedFired;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, downloadItem);
        }
        ///This is where i want to make the control visible but i cant seem to reference it.
        panelDownloads.Visible = true;   
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is the event `OnDownloadUpdatedFired` registered?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling, I added this to your code. I think this is right. Hope it helps, or at least gives you a start:

```
DownloadHandler downer = new DownloadHandler(this);
browser.DownloadHandler = downer;
downer.OnBeforeDownloadFired += OnBeforeDownloadFired;
downer.OnDownloadUpdatedFired += OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

private void OnBeforeDownloadFired(object sender, DownloadItem e)
{
    this.UpdateDownloadAction("OnBeforeDownload", e);
}

private void OnDownloadUpdatedFired(object sender, DownloadItem e)
{
    this.UpdateDownloadAction("OnDownloadUpdated", e);
}

private void UpdateDownloadAction(string downloadAction, DownloadItem downloadItem)
{
    /*
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var viewModel = (BrowserTabViewModel)this.DataContext;
        viewModel.LastDownloadAction = downloadAction;
        viewModel.DownloadItem = downloadItem;
    });
    */
}

// ...

public class DownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

    MainForm mainForm;

    public DownloadHandler(MainForm form)
    {
        mainForm = form;
    }

// ...
```

Comment: This helped solve a nagging issue with downloading files (eg .mobi ebook) if the download link had the target "_blank".

If there was no target, a download dialog was triggered. With a _blank target, I had to suppress a popup window and open a new custom tab in my browser, but when this happened, a download dialog was not triggered.